# Facebook like working on some pages but not others

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Facebook like's are working on some pages of my site but not others. I can't show an example on the live site as I have taken the functionality down, however working directly on the developers like button page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

If you try http://www.rscpp.co.uk/ you can successfully like the page. But it won't let me like http://www.rscpp.co.uk/counselling.html

I have tried putting both in the linter:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint

Both show some required items missing, but as I'm not trying to provide opengraph information I think these can be ignored? Oddly though, the like button for the http://www.rscpp.co.uk/counselling.html page does work when done through the linter (which is done through an iFrame rather than the code that the facebook like button creator gives you).

I can't see that there is any 301 redirect, SSL or so on issue with the http://www.rscpp.co.uk/counselling.html that may cause any problem.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You don't have any Facebook code on your counselling page.

Comment: Hi Neil, no I don't at present, as I said above I have taken it down as it's not working. However if you try setting up the button for that page through: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
You will see Facebook creates the button there, and it doesn't work there, just as it doesn't work when actually on my site. But it does work for the homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the `appId` of your application, but this should work:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=xxx&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like href="http://www.rscpp.co.uk/counselling.html" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>
```

Comment: Thanks Neil, that is what I have been using all day, but it's only worked on selected URLs, somehow  seems to work on them all now, i think there is something up with facebook...

Comment: Yes this seems to be the solution, although it is what I started with, and doesn't really identify what was going wrong, maybe facebook / internet issues, but odd that they seemed to be confined to certain pages.